# Maven restricting dependencies to release artifacts

Tags: maven

We are building release versions of an application which has a set of artifacts, with dependencies between them. While building the release version , we would like to restrict dependency resolution for these to be only release versions.

We had a couple of issues while doing that - both interrelated - so a single mail

1. When we defined dependency ranges as [1.1,1.2) , and a version for 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT was available , it resolved to that version rather than a 1.1.2 version - which was the highest release version. We were able to get around this by giving [1.0-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT ) but that seemed crude, so wanted to check with the group whether there is a better way
2. To prevent snapshot releases being used we restricted snapshots in the repository definition of pom.xml as follows

> ```
>    <repository> 
>        <id>forward-deploy</id>                 
>        <url>https://server/nexus/public/</url> 
>        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
>    </repository>
> ```

along with dependency being set to

> ```
>    <version>[1.1-1.2)</version>
> ```

This prevented the artifact from being downloaded, but it caused a compilation error as dependency resolution attempted to resolve to version  1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Any suggestions about the right way to address this would be helpful.

Note: I am using mvn version 3.0.5

Comment: First is to prevent using version ranges is the best and simplest solution...furthermore POM's shouldn't contain repository definitions...better use the definition in the settings.xml only and much more better  use a repository manager to handle that in a better way...Apart from the above if you have a released version 1.2 why does a 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT exist? It should be removed if the 1.2 release is done (using a repository manager which is configured correctly will prevent such things).

Comment: We build the trunk ( SNAPTSHOT ) and the branch ( release ) in different folders on the same m/c. So how do we indicate that this is a release build and so restrict dependencies to only release artefacts ? I thought we could do it in the POM - hence the repository definition in the POM. Also I did not say 1.2 release is done - the release version is 1.1.2, but a version range of  [1.1-1.2) is taking 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.1.2 which is what I expected